# R- stacked charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate

Hi I'm having issues with a stacked bar chart.

The goal is to print a bar chart that shows the sum of products sold stacked on top of each other, which I have done, but the products are not grouped together, so instead of having big blocks per product, they are all split.  I need some way to aggregate the count, so it sums and then I can add the chart in some sort of order

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(plyr) #Is this automatically loaded with ggplot2? 
library(dplyr)

salesMixData <- read.csv("SalesMix.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

productMix <- salesMixData[,c(1,6,7)]

ggplot(productMix, aes(x=JoinMonthYear, y=Count,fill=Prod)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust = 1),legend.position="bottom")
```

The output looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: For future reference, it's easier for everyone if you provide a self-contained example.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to `summarise` the data first, calculating an aggregate sum for each combination of `JoinMonthYear` and `Prod`.

Here's an example with a dummy data set:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(x=sample(20, 1000, replace=T), 
                count=rpois(1000, 10),
                grp=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

This is equivalent to what you're seeing:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=count, fill=grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Grouping the observations (in your case by `JoinMonthYear` and `Prod`), and then summarising to the groups' sums, should get you what you're after:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(x, grp) %>%
  summarise(sum_count=sum(count, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=sum_count, fill=grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]